# Конвертация из cp1251 в utf8

Tags: python, кодировка

Собственно, весь вопрос в заголовке. Я использую вот такой код:

```
with codecs.open( sourceFileName, "r",  "cp1251", ) as sourceFile:
    contents = sourceFile.read()

with codecs.open( sourceFileName, "w", "utf-8") as targetFile:
    if contents:
        targetFile.write(contents)
```

И получаю следующую ошибку:

> "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 625: character maps to <undefined>"

В похожих вопросах решения не нашел. Python 2.7

UPD: Опытным путем установил, что ошибку вызывает заглавная русская буква "И". Даже если файл только ее и содержит.

UPD2: Оказалось, что я олень и пытался повторно сконвертировать уже сконвертированный файл.

Comment: Ну нет такой буквы в этом слове, пардон в cp1251. Надо смотреть, что у Вас в файле. Возможно, что там не cp1251

Comment: Я вполне уверен, что этот файл в ср1251, я ведь сам его писал.

Comment: @alexlz Опытным путем выяснил, что ругается он на букву "И" заглавную.

Comment: Заглавная "И" -- 0xc8, а не 0x98.

Comment: (развел руками) я обратного и не утверждаю. Но ругается ведь!

Comment: Попробовал вот так (на почту коммент с предложением пришел, а тут его почему-то не видно):

    with open(sourceFileName, "rb") as sourceFileBin:
        contents = sourceFileBin.read().decode(sourceEncoding)

    with open(sourceFileName, "wb") as targetFile:
        targetFile.write( contents.encode("unt-8"))

Но ошибка та же самая!

Comment: А нельзя ли увидеть сам файл? Если хотите -- преобразуйте файл (напр. с помощью iconv) в utf8

     iconv -f cp1251 -t utf-8 f.1251 -o f.utf8

В случае ошибок можно добавить пропуск неправильных символов ( -c )

     iconv -c -f cp1251 -t utf-8 f.1251 -o f.utf8

И сравните файлы